# "initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue" Error

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, dynamic-memory-allocation, lvalue

So I'm making a function to differentiate a polynomial. Here's the function:

```
void differentiate (double coefficients[], int & degree);

void differentiate (double coefficients[], int & degree){
    int *p_n{&degree};
    int p{*p_n};
    coefficients[p]=0;
    for (int i=0;i<p+1;i++){
        coefficients[i]=(coefficients[i+1])*(i+1);
    }
}
```

And this is my `main()` function:

```
int main(){
    double arr[3]{3,1,5};
    std::cout<<differentiate(arr,2)<<std::endl;
}
```

However, when I try to use this function in my `main()` function, it gives me this error saying:

> initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue

I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the pointer, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: It should be noted that your function accesses `coefficients` out of bounds. The loop runs from 0 to `degree`, where `degree` is 2. But then the indexing adds 1. So, if `degree` is providing the maximum possible index into an array, your function is then accessing past that index in the last iteration of the loop, and you'll get undefined behavior.

Comment: Another error: you are trying to do `std::cout << differentiate(...)`, but your `differentiate` function returns `void`. You need a value to be able to `cout` it, not `void`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the parameter `int & degree` which is a *reference*. You cannot bind a (non-constant) reference to a literal value, which in your case is the integer literal `2` in the call:

```
differentiate(arr,2)
```

In simple terms, the use of a reference parameter allows the caller to provide a modifiable object as that parameter, and any changes to it will be reflected in the caller. The term *lvalue* in C++ lingo means a modifiable object. So in essence, the error message is quite specific about the problem.

To fix this, observe that you don't actually need to modify the value `degree`, and since it's also not a giant datatype, you don't need to pass a reference at all. Simply pass it by value:

```
void differentiate (double coefficients[], int degree);
void differentiate (double coefficients[], int degree){
    int *p_n{&degree};
    int p{*p_n};
    coefficients[p]=0;
    for (int i=0;i<p+1;i++){
        coefficients[i]=(coefficients[i+1])*(i+1);
    }
}
```

Now, let's look at the convoluted way you use `degree`:

```
int *p_n{&degree};
int p{*p_n};
for (int i = 0; i < p+1; i++) //...
```

This is a very roundabout way of doing this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < degree+1; i++) //...
```

So I would suggest you simplify the function to make it more readable.

Comment: Another way to fix it is to change the reference to a const reference, which can bind to a constant

Comment: That's technically correct, but a const reference to `int` is not good style (in my opinion, and by general convention). You might end up with that kind of thing as a result of more generic code using function templates, but I think explicitly writing `const int & param` is an anti-pattern.

Comment: @paddy Can I make changes to my function code without disturbing the int & degree parameter (if possible)?

Comment: Yes, you can create a variable in the caller: `int degree = 2;` and then pass it when you call the function: `differentiate(arr, degree)`